# How to add legend to ggplot2 line with point plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have tried many codes, but always fail to add legend for the graph.I want to add legend for measured red point and simulated black line[The graph is still missing legend with the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQVRJ.png)

```
    library(foreign)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(readxl)
    library(scales)
    Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
    X0_40cm <- read_excel("C:/Users/Connie/Desktop/LAI/Wheat_2017-2018.xlsx")
    View(X0_40cm)
    ggplot(X0_40cm, aes(Date,LAI,group=1))+
      geom_point(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Measured"),col="red")+
      geom_line(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Simulated"),col="black")+
      theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0.80))+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,3)) +
      labs(title="Winter wheat of I plot",y="LAI",x="Date")+
      theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An automatic legend is only drawn if you map a variable on the color aesthetic. In your case map Condition on color and set colors manually. Try this:

```
    ggplot(mapping = aes(Date, LAI, color = Condition, linetype = Condition, shape = Condition))+
  geom_point(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Measured"))+
  geom_line(data=subset(X0_40cm, Condition=="Simulated"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(NA,1)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,NA)) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0.80))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,3)) +
  labs(title="Winter wheat of I plot",y="LAI",x="Date")
  theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! It works! But what if the "red" is point and "black" is line, how should I adjust?

Comment: Hi Lin. Just edited my code. You also have to map `Condition` on linetype and shape and set the scales for these aesthetics manually too.