# ggplot for a FULL legend of both dots and linear shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to add two simple linear regression with ggplot in just a single plot. but the problem is that when I am trying to add legend for values and lines, the error is that row are different in two datasets. How can i fix that while I have a desirable legend in the plot both for values and lines with desirable colors? 
example: I have a dataset that I randomly divided into two smaller datasets. What I want is that I want to have A SINGLE PLOT where I have simple linear regression of the whole dataset (a) and one for the smaller dataset(d or e) all in one plot, with a full legend both for dots (which dot belongs to which dataset, and for lines with different colours for each one). Column c says that which value belongs to which dataset.

```
a <- 
V1   V2   V3
a1   b1   d 
a2   b2   d
a3   b3   e
a4   b4   e
a5   b5   d
a6   b6   e
a7   b7   e
a8   b8   d
a9   b9   d
a10  b10  d

d <-
V1  V2 
a1  b1
a2  b2
a5  b5
a8  b8 
a9  b9
a10 b10  

e <-
V1  V2 
a3  b3
a4  b4
a6  b6
a7  b7
```

Notice: The number of rows for datasets is different from each other.
I use geom_line like this. I do not want to use geom_smooth.

```
 r = lm(formula = V2 ~ V1,
                data = e)
   geom_line(data = e, aes(x = V1, y = predict(r, newdata = e)),
              col = "e", size = 1)
```

But when I use

```
scale_color_manual(name="something", values=c("a"="blue","e"="green"))
```

the programme throws an error that :

```
Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you variables are numbers ... Using geom_smooth (i checked with `mtcars`):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(a, aes(V1, V2, color = V3)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = "all"), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

To manually adjust the legends see e.g. here: [How to add legend to ggplot2 line with point plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556330/how-to-add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-with-point-plot/60556435#60556435)

Computing regression lines manually and using `geom_line`. Using `mtcars` (V1 = mpg, V2 = hp, V3 = cyl) as example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(p_all = predict(lm(hp ~ mpg, .))) %>% 
  group_split(cyl) %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, p_cyl = predict(lm(hp ~ mpg, .x)))) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "dataset")

ggplot(df, aes(mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hp)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = p_cyl, group = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = p_all, color = "all"))
```

The idea is to first add predicted values for the whole dataset (p_all) then split the dataset, add predicted values for each of the datasets (p_cyl) and binding them back together. The idea of plotting in a single plot is essentially the same as with using `geom_smooth`.

And if you just want to plot a regression line for only one of you datasets than this works basically the same. Just adjust the scales manually. Hope that I getting closer to the plot which you had in mind (;:

```
ggplot(df, aes(mpg, color = factor(cyl), linetype = factor(cyl), shape = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hp)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = p_all, color = "all", linetype = "all", , shape = "all")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = p_cyl, group = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, NA, NA, 1)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 16, 16, NA))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying with geom_line. Do you know how can I fix this via geom_line?

Comment: I made some extra explanation above. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. You are right, but it did not work in my code. I am trying to add a legend for lines, one line is for predicted values and another one for the whole dataset. My geom_line is like I wrote and colour is defined as a name, then I gave a name of true colour via  'scale_color_manual ', but it does not work.@stefan

Comment: I found that your number of rows are the same. But my datasets differ in terms of number of rows @stefan

Comment: Hi R_mad. First. The number of rows in mtcars when spitting by cyl is not the same. Check `count(mtcars, cyl)`. So this is basically similar to your data. Second. Let `ggplot2` do the work. Instead of splitting your dataset and plotting separately, just use the whole dataset and specify the aesthetics. Third and generally speaking, provide a minimal example of your dataset and your code and not only some kind of informal description. Makes it much easier to check whether my solution works for your data or how to adjust your code to make it work.